# Identity and Access Tool. not listing in vs2012 menu

Tags: azure, acs

I have installed Identity and Access Tool version 1.1.0, after successful installation I have restarted VS2012 but still I was not able to see "Identity and Access" in the project menu.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure project type is set to `.NET Framework 4.5` and not 4 else 'Identity and Access' wont show.

Also ensure the project type is **not** set to `.NET Framework 4.5.1` as that doesn't work either.

Comment: I am surprised why it works only when Target version is 4.5 and doesn't work when selected version is 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 as I would these are in place upgrade of .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right clicking on the web project? It should be there in the context menu as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I right clicked web project. No Luck, I could not see Identity and Access...

Answer (score 1):

Check the Framework Version. The I&A Tool wont show in projects targeting .net Framework 4.5.1
or at least this was the reason on my dev-machine.

Switching to 4.5 worked like charm.